# "describe is not defined" in Vitest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsx, vite, vitest

I'm starting out with Vite for a React application but unable to get jest tests working. I am trying to use Vitest with experimental ES module.

I am getting:

```
FAIL  src/App.test.tsx [ src/App.test.tsx ]
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

I have added Jest, Mocha Vite, and Vitest, but it hasn't helped.

My package.json has

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vitest": "^0.29.8"
  }
```

My Vite config is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
}
```

My Vitest config is:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.tsx'],
  },
})
```

This is from running Vitest. If I run Jest directly with

```
jest
```

or

```
node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

I get:

```
 SyntaxError: /home/durrantm/Dropnot/vite/thedeiscorecard-vite/src/App.test.tsx: 
 Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
```

Comment: Jest and vitest are different libraries to accomplish the same thing, you want one or the other, not both unless you know you specifically have a reason to need both (ie, a gradual migration from one to the other).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

your test code is using global mode you must enable it:

vitest.config.ts

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.tsx'],
    globals: true
  },
})
```

also if you are using typescript you need to add styles to benefit the hint:
tsconfig.json

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  }
}
```

> Although vitest APIs are designed to be jest friendly, it doesn't mean jest can run test code written for vitest

Answer (score 5):

You need to import `describe` from vitest.

```js
import { describe } from 'vitest';
```